# How to properly include C header file in macOS Swift Xcode project for `proc_selfpid` function?

Tags: c, swift, xcode, macos, xnu

I have a simple project with code:

```swift
import Foundation

let p1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<rusage_info_t?>.allocate(capacity: 1)

let spid = proc_selfpid()
let s = proc_pid_rusage(579, 0, p1)
if s == KERN_SUCCESS {
    // ...

}

print("Status \(status)")
```

I've added a bridging header:

```
#ifndef Header_h
#define Header_h
#include <libproc.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>

#endif /* Header_h */
```

But it strangely cannot find `proc_selfpid` saying `Cannot find 'proc_selfpid' in scope`

while it finds `proc_pid_rusage` fine.

I found the definition of `proc_pid_rusage` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/libproc.h`

I can find the definition of `proc_selfpid` here `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX13.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Kernel.framework/Versions/A/Headers/sys/proc.h`

I wonder how can I use that SDK implementation in a Swift project?

I have this environment:

```bash
uname -mrsv
Darwin 22.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.4.0: Mon Mar  6 20:59:28 PST 2023; root:xnu-8796.101.5~3/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 arm64
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use `ProcessInfo.processInfo.processIdentifier`?

Comment: I need other functions too, ie `proc_selfppid`, `proc_find`.

Comment: Your newer question is basically a duplicate of this one, should I close this one? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76034307/3141234

Comment: It's completely different, I see 2 different header files locations and there's no information how it's used by Swift environment? Why one header can be included by bridging and the other won't? It's still a puzzle to me.