# How to use `proc_pid_rusage` result in Swift using UnsafeMutablePointer?

Tags: c, swift, xcode, macos, xnu

I tried this code to get result from `proc_pid_rusage`:

```swift
import Foundation

let p1 = UnsafeMutablePointer<rusage_info_t?>.allocate(capacity: 1)

let spid = ProcessInfo.processInfo.processIdentifier
let status = proc_pid_rusage(spid, 0, p1)
if status == KERN_SUCCESS {
    // ...
    let umrp : rusage_info_t = p1.pointee!
    let a = umrp.load(as:rusage_info_v0.self)
    print("User time \(a.ri_user_time)")
}

print("Status \(status)")
```

`rusage_info_t`, as Xcode says, is defined as:

```swift
public typealias rusage_info_t = UnsafeMutableRawPointer
```

I assume that it should point to a struct `rusage_info_v0` as I specified `flavor` = 0. But I get this runtime error:

```
Swift/UnsafeRawPointer.swift:1203: Fatal error: load from misaligned raw pointer
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I don't understand what alignment should be and how should I specify that.

Comment: How about `umrp.loadUnaligned`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/43876992/3141234 Most of the `proc` APIs take pointers to where they should store the result. You usually don't want to allocate new heap memory to point to. INstead, make a local variable of the correct type, and pass a pointer to that local variable with `&`. The proc API will fill it in for you, no heap allocation required

Comment: `loadUnaligned` throws a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. That helped me to get the result. I wonder if I can do the same with the heap allocated memory?

Comment: @egor10_4 You can, but why? (By the way, people don't get notified of comments to others' posts unless you mentioned them)